# Should tags polarity/connotation be created?

Tags: discussion, tags

While [writing my question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/), I thought it would fall under the category [connotation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotation) or [polarity](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polarity).

By polarity I am refering to the phenomenon that for example `cheap` could be something good (`a cheap car is hard to come by`) or something bad (`that cheap car is all you can afford to buy?`).

We've got a tag [polarity-items](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polarity-items), but judging from the three questions it was used for, it seems to be about `polarity` as in `positive and negative sentences`, and not `positive/negative connotation`.

Any opinions, or can anybody create [connotation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotation) / [polarity](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polarity)?

Comment: Anybody can create polarity, but I think that would be confusing since that isn't what polarity generally means in linguistics (or in English more generally in my experience).  I can write something longer later, but see:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_polarity and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_items  On the other hand, a connotation tag sounds like it'd be fine.

Comment: Yes, now that I think about I think you're right. `polarity` is probably not the best tag, especially as what I meant id essentially pos./neg. connotation. I'd say there's no need for a longer answer/explanation, but feel free if you'd like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @snailboat, `polarity` is not used in this way usually.

I've created the tag [connotation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotation) and proposed a tag wiki for it. (**Accepted, now active.**)

> Questions regarding commonly understood cultural or emotional associations of a word or a phrase, as opposed to the word's or phrase's explicit or literal meaning, which is called its denotation.
>
> For example, both 化粧室 and 便所 denote the same object (bathroom or toilet), but the former carries a positive ("clean"), the latter a negative ("dirty") connotation.